# How to remove the auto start authorization of 'citrix receiver' software from my computer?

Tags: windows-7, citrix-receiver, authorization

I am having trouble because every time I start my computer this software always tries to pop an *add account* dialog and indirectly makes my computer slow. So I tried to disable it but I couldn't make it.

[image: add account]

I also tried to peak into the properties of the software so any help will be appreciated. I have read [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1020012/disabling-startup-apps-for-a-single-user-profile-while-leaving-them-enabled-for) and it is nowhere duplicate of mine

[image: properties]

Comment: Why don't you just uninstall that software? You aren't using it anyway.

Comment: i actually share my pc with my brother and he always use this software for his professional work so please try to give some sensible answer cause solution of every problem is not just uninstall and then install it again

Comment: Possible duplicate of [disabling startup apps for a single user profile while leaving them enabled for other profiles](https://superuser.com/questions/1020012/disabling-startup-apps-for-a-single-user-profile-while-leaving-them-enabled-for)

Comment: And please tone down your comments because it's coming up as unfriendly already. And next time make sure you post all the relevant information in the question itself. Namely, in this case, that there is another user needing said software and that *you* need a way to selectively disable such startup program for one user only.

Comment: please why don't u read ur first comment in that u have written "why dont u just uninstall the software" wasn't that unfriendly? and also plzz let it be if u dont want to help don't do it my question was fine but your comment was not acceptable for anyone.

Comment: please it's nowhere duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/1020012/disabling-startup-apps-for-a-single-user-profile-while-leaving-them-enabled-for  try to help me if u know something for citrix if u dont know then plzz dont comment

Comment: _"why dont u just uninstall the software" wasn't that unfriendly?_ - No, of course not.

Comment: @n8te canyou give me some other alternate answer rather than uninstalling please because i dont want to uninstall?

Comment: you're looking at no where. Why on earth do you open the exe files' properties to look for disabling startup option? First open application's settings and see if there's any "start with Windows" option and turn if off. If there isn't any, open [msconfig](https://kb.iu.edu/d/adlf) and see where the program is coming from and disable it

Comment: @phuclv thnx for giving a general idea for how to disable it

Answer (score 2):

From my experience, which is almost identical to yours, once Citrix is in your computer, it is IN in a very subversive way, to be honest. In our case, it wasn’t just uploading files of one our family (it’s client)  but ALL of the users on our computer! Once this was realised, it was removed from the computer and even, that wasn’t straight forward. Uninstalling from the the Control Panel/Programs/Uninstall a Program only goes so far. Citrix leaves Receivers hooked deeply buried in the Users of your C drive. It takes a while, but it is possible to find them and rid you computer of them in the end.

Answer (score 0):

This Citrix document address your issue.
https://support.citrix.com/article/CTX135438

You will have to import the receiver admx and adml templates from receiver installation directory to policy definitions folders under windows to manger Citrix receiver policy.